# Python: ¿Cómo encripto archivos usando AES? (Crypto.Cipher)

Tags: python-2.7, encriptación

Seré breve, el caso es que tengo como proyecto el encriptar y desencriptar archivos (Cualquier tipo de archivo) utilizando el método AES-256. Pero no entiendo porque algunos archivos de texto sí puedo encriptarlos/desencriptarlos y otros no... También pasa con imágenes, etc. Mi profesor nos dió lo sugerencia de **realizar una lectura a nivel binario** y **utilizar un "buffer"** para la lectura... Alguna sugerencia?

Aquí mi código:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import sys
import os

opc = sys.argv[1]
direccion = sys.argv[2]
key = sys.argv[3].split("=")[1]
iv = "1234567890123456"
tam = os.path.getsize(direccion)

def encriptar(dire,key,iv):
    encriptador = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    archivo = open(dire,"r")
    archivo_encriptado = open("encriptado.enc","w")
    while True:
        data = archivo.read(16)
        n = len(data)
        if n == 0:
            break
        elif n % 16 != 0:
            data += ' ' * (16 - n % 16)
        enc = encriptador.encrypt(data)
        archivo_encriptado.write(enc)

def desencriptar(dire,key,iv):
    archivo = open(dire,"rb")
    tam = os.path.getsize(dire)
    encriptador = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    archivo_desencriptado = open("desencriptado.txt", 'w')
    while True:
        data = archivo.read(256)
        n = len(data)
        if n == 0:
            break
        decd = encriptador.decrypt(data)
        n = len(decd)
        if tam > n:
            archivo_desencriptado.write(decd)
        else:
            archivo_desencriptado.write(decd[:tam])
        tam -= n

if(opc == "e"):
    encriptar(direccion,key,iv)
else:
    desencriptar(direccion,key,iv)
```

[image]

El error que me salta al realizar otro tipo de encriptacion.

Por cierto, tendría que usar el cifrado AES-256.

Answer (score 0):

Deberías usar bytes para leer y para escribir, en lugar de caracteres. Para ello basta que abras los ficheros en modo binario (añadiendo una `"b"` al modo).

Eso implica también cambiar el relleno a `b" "` para que sea un byte (con el ascii del espacio en blanco) en lugar de un caracter.

Recuerda también cerrar los ficheros cuando hayas terminado de leer o escribir en ellos.

Con estos cambios tu código queda así:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import sys
import os

opc = sys.argv[1]
direccion = sys.argv[2]
key = sys.argv[3].split("=")[1]
iv = "1234567890123456"
tam = os.path.getsize(direccion)

def encriptar(dire,key,iv):
    encriptador = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    archivo = open(dire,"rb")
    archivo_encriptado = open("encriptado.enc","wb")
    while True:
        data = archivo.read(16)
        n = len(data)
        if n == 0:
            break
        elif n % 16 != 0:
            data += b' ' * (16 - n % 16)
        enc = encriptador.encrypt(data)
        archivo_encriptado.write(enc)
    archivo.close()
    archivo_encriptado.close()

def desencriptar(dire,key,iv):
    archivo = open(dire,"rb")
    tam = os.path.getsize(dire)
    encriptador = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    archivo_desencriptado = open("desencriptado.txt", 'wb')
    while True:
        data = archivo.read(256)
        n = len(data)
        if n == 0:
            break
        decd = encriptador.decrypt(data)
        n = len(decd)
        if tam > n:
            archivo_desencriptado.write(decd)
        else:
            archivo_desencriptado.write(decd[:tam])
        tam -= n
    archivo.close()
    archivo_desencriptado.close()

if(opc == "e"):
    encriptar(direccion,key,iv)
else:
    desencriptar(direccion,key,iv)
```

Esta versión no "rompe", sino que aparentemente codifica y decodifica bien diferentes archivos. Sin embargo no está del todo bien porque en la decodificación se incluyen al final los espacios de relleno. De hecho, no tienes forma de saber una vez has decodificado el archivo si los espacios que aparecen al final de la versión decodificada son los que habías metido de relleno, o si ya estaban ahi en el archivo original.

En un archivo de texto el meter espacios al final no suele ser problema (aunque estrictamente la desencriptación no es correcta, pues no estás recuperando *exactamente* el archivo original, sino uno que "se ve casi igual", salvo por los espacios finales). En un archivo binario en cambio los espacios finales pueden dejarlo inutilizable, según el formato que sea. Por ejemplo los archivos `.zip` tienen al final el "directorio" del fichero, y meterle espacios podría confundir a la utilidad `unzip`.

Un truco que he visto por ahi consiste en lo siguiente. En lugar de usar un espacio en blanco para rellenar, usas un byte cuyo valor indica la longitud del relleno. Por ejemplo, si sólo tienes que rellenar con un byte, el relleno sería `\x01`. Si tienes que rellenar con tres, sería `\x03\x03\x03`, etc. En caso de que no sea necesario relleno, puedes rellenar igualmente con 16 bytes de valor 0.

De este modo, tras desencriptar, miras el valor del último byte de la versión desencriptada y si encuentras 0 sabes que tienes que eliminar los últimos 16 bytes, si encuentras 03 sabes que son solo 3 bytes los que hay que eliminar, etc.